# Install IPython on Ubuntu 12.04 VirtualBox Guest and use it from the browser on the Windows Host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ipython, jupyter-notebook

On the guest machine (Ubuntu 12.04), I have installed ipython and ipython-notebook from the repositories as usual. Then I run the ipython notebook to start the server and try to access the page from the browser of the host (running Windows 7), but it won't connect.

The ipython server is running on the default port 8888. I have tried using the NAT configuration for the VM and route ports 8888 from host to 8888 on guest, but without success. I have tried using bridged networking as well, but I'm not sure which direction I should enter in the browser. Is it the host ip for eth0 shown with the ifconfig command, on port 8888?

Is it possible to get this configuration to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IPython Notebook runs on localhost by default.  I don't think the loopback interface of the VM is visible to the Host OS.  You will have to instruct the notebook to listen on the VM's 'public' IP with

```
ipython notebook --ip=a.b.c.d
```

then you should be able to connect from your host.

You can also set this value permanently as `NotebookApp.ip = 'a.b.c.d'` in ipython_notebook_config.py.

Comment: Works great now! I've checked it's possible to use either NAT or bridged networking. With NAT the ip needs to be the one shown using the ifconfig command (and ports forwarded appropiately). With bridged networking, the ip is the one assigned by the router, and is shown with ifconfig too. Just to clarify for anybody else.